# What is the best way to store geodata (spatial data) for a small open source web application

Tags: php, zend-framework, geolocation, gis, openmap

I'm about to start developing a GIS web application.

I'll use PHP as language, Zend as Framework and Google Maps API for map rendering, but I didn't decided which back-end storage I'm going to use.

I'll need:

1. Store: Points (Lat & Lng) , Lines (Set of points), Polygons
2. Make queries like:

   - "Which are the n Points of a given kind nearest of some other given Point ?"
   - "Which are the n Points of a given kind nearest of some given Line ?"
   - "Are point 'a' inside polygon 'g'?"
   - "What is the distance from point 'a' to point 'b' ?"
3. Combine these spatial data types with other relational data in the same table.

Which open source technology should I use?

Comment: Decide whether you are going to need spatial indexes or if you are happy enough with just lat, lngs.  Might come down to the Q: Are you dealing with polygons and lines or just points?  Likewise, are you going to rely heavily on kml or are you going to spoon-feed data to gmaps.  Take a close look at Google Fusion Tables and see if/how that could be helpful either as a proxy for public facing data, or as a geocoding tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're allowed to choose any storage - then you might prefer the ones, that support spatial indexes, like PostgreSQL (postgis) <strike>or MongoDB</strike> or mysql

Comment: ...and mysql - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-a-spatial-index.html - NB using a nosql database has much further implications - unless you really know what you're doing I'd recommend stearing clear of mongo DB